# XSLT Traceability Matrix - Ideas?

Tags: xml, xslt, uml

So, I am pretty proficient in writing XSLT stylesheets for normal one-pass document conversion. (XML flavor A to XML flavor B)  However, now I have a little problem that runs into the classic XSLT-is-not-a-procedural language problem and am looking for some ideas.

I have a SysML 1.3 requirements model that maps source requirements to clarified requirements and clarified requirements to allocated systems and testcases. The tool will generate some very simple matrices, but I want to get more control of the output.

The actual XMI file for the SysML model is gobbeldygoook hard to read, so I will create a little simplified grammar here to describe with the problem. My data looks like this:

```
<requirement id="REQ01">The device shall heat water</requirement>
<requirement id="REQ02">The device shall fry eggs</requirement>
<requirement id="REQ03">The device shall prepare coffee</requirement>
<requirement id="REQ04">The device shall cook bacon</requirement>
<device id="DEV01">
    <name>Coffee Maker</name>
    <relationship refid="REQ01" type="Satisfy"/>
    <relationship refid="REQ03" type="Satisfy"/>
</device>
<device id="DEV02">
    <name>Frying Pan</name>
    <relationship refid="REQ02" type="Satisfy"/>
    <relationship refid="REQ04" type="Satisfy"/>
</device>
```

What I want do do is parse this file and output a CSV file
that has one row which is a header containing all the device names
and one row for each requirement with an 'X' in the column
for the device that satisfies the requirements.

Any suggestions for how to best go about this -short of using something
totally different like Java? Thanks.

Comment: I am probably missing something here, but why is this such a big problem? You just need to create (for each requirement) a cell for each device, and use a key to determine the status.   P.S. your example is missing a root element

Comment: device-to-requirement - is it 1:N or N:M relationship?

Comment: The device-to-requirement relationship is N:M. Many requirements might be satisfied with one device. Many devices might satisfy one requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by use of two separate templates matching **device** with the **mode** property to distinguish them, and with use of parameters in a template.

For a start, as it will involving matching **device** elements in multiple places, you could define a variable to hold them

```
<xsl:variable name="devices" select="//device" />
```

Doing the header row is obviously straight-forward. For each row you would select each **requirement** with apply-templates, but within this template you would them select the **devices** variable, passing in the requirement id as a parameter:

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$devices" mode="requirement">
     <xsl:with-param name="reqid" select="@id" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
```

Then, you would have a second template matching **device**, with this mode, that takes in the parameter and checks if the relevant relationship exist

```
<xsl:template match="device" mode="requirement">
   <xsl:param name="reqid" />
   <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
   <xsl:if test="relationship[@refid=$reqid]">X</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text" />

   <xsl:variable name="devices" select="//device" />
   <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#10;'" />

   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:text>Requirement,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$devices" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="requirement" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="device">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="device" mode="requirement">
      <xsl:param name="reqid" />
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:if test="relationship[@refid=$reqid]">X</xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="requirement">
      <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$devices" mode="requirement">
         <xsl:with-param name="reqid" select="@id" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, if you were using XSLT 2.0, you could use the **xsl:value-of** with a separator specified, to output the header row, which would then leave you only needing one template matching **device**, removing the need for the mode. Something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$devices/@id" separator="," />
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked perfectly using SaxonHE. Now I can build on this simple base and gradually work up to parsing the actually much more complicated XMI file product by the SysML modeling tool.